# Pandas why does my column datatype change?

Tags: python, pandas

Please could someone explain why when I create a simple heterogeneous dataframe with pandas, the datatypes change when I access each row individually.

e.g.

```
scene_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'magnitude': np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.3, (10,)),
    'x-center': np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (10,)),
    'y-center': np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (10,)),
    'label': np.random.randint(2, size=(10,), dtype='u1')})

scene_df.dtypes
```

prints:

```
label          uint8
magnitude    float64
x-center     float64
y-center     float64
dtype: object
```

but when I iterate rows:

```
[r['label'].dtype for i, r in scene_df.iterrows()]
```

I get float64 for labels

```
[dtype('float64'),
 dtype('float64'),
 dtype('float64'),
 dtype('float64'),
 dtype('float64'),
...
```

Edit:

To answer what I was planning to do with this:

```
def square(mag, x, y):
    wh = np.array([mag, mag])
    pos = np.array((x, y)) - wh/2
    return plt.Rectangle(pos, *wh)

def circle(mag, x, y):
    return plt.Circle((x, y), mag)

shape_fn_lookup = [square, circle]
```

Which ends up as this ugly piece of code:

```
[shape_fn_lookup[int(s['label'])](
        *s[['magnitude', 'x-center', 'y-center']])
 for i, s in scene_df.iterrows()]
```

Which gives a bunch of circles and squares that I might plot:

```
[<matplotlib.patches.Circle at 0x7fcf3ea00d30>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Circle at 0x7fcf3ea00f60>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x7fcf3eb4da90>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Circle at 0x7fcf3eb4d908>,
...
]
```

Even `DataFrame.to_dict('records')` does this datatype conversion:

```
type(scene_df.to_dict('records')[0]['label'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using itertuples instead of interrows because iterrows returns a Series for each row, it does not preserve dtypes across the rows (dtypes are preserved across columns for DataFrames).

```
[type(r.label) for r in scene_df.itertuples()]
```

Output:

```
[numpy.uint8,
 numpy.uint8,
 numpy.uint8,
 numpy.uint8,
 numpy.uint8,
 numpy.uint8,
 numpy.uint8,
 numpy.uint8,
 numpy.uint8,
 numpy.uint8]
```

Comment: Yes this is much nicer for my use case:
`[shape_fn_lookup[s](*rest) for i, s, *rest in scene_df.itertuples()]`

Answer (score 1):

Because `iterrows()` returns a Series with the index made of the column names for each row.

Pandas.Series has only one dtype, so it will be downcasted to `float64`:

```
In [163]: first_row = list(scene_df.iterrows())[0][1]

In [164]: first_row
Out[164]:
label        0.000000
magnitude    0.293681
x-center    -0.628142
y-center    -0.218315
Name: 0, dtype: float64   # <--------- NOTE

In [165]: type(first_row)
Out[165]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [158]: [(type(r), r.dtype) for i, r in scene_df.iterrows()]
Out[158]:
[(pandas.core.series.Series, dtype('float64')),
 (pandas.core.series.Series, dtype('float64')),
 (pandas.core.series.Series, dtype('float64')),
 (pandas.core.series.Series, dtype('float64')),
 (pandas.core.series.Series, dtype('float64')),
 (pandas.core.series.Series, dtype('float64')),
 (pandas.core.series.Series, dtype('float64')),
 (pandas.core.series.Series, dtype('float64')),
 (pandas.core.series.Series, dtype('float64')),
 (pandas.core.series.Series, dtype('float64'))]
```

Comment: So is there any sensible way to avoid the downcasting?

Comment: You can represent `int` as `float` without loosing any information, but not vice versa. As i said above Pandas.Series must have a single `dtype`

Comment: @FrankWilson, are you sure you need to loop at all? Pandas allows us to do almost everything in a vectorized way, not using loops...